# How do I refrence a non- static method from a static context

Tags: java, constructor, static

I have this constructor with a function however when i compile my main method i non-static method area cannot be referenced from a static context. I know its a simple fix i just cant quite get there. Thanks

```
public class Rect{
     private double x, y, width, height;

     public Rect (double x1, double newY, double newWIDTH, double newHEIGHT){
       x = x1;
       y = newY;
       width = newWIDTH;
       height = newHEIGHT;

    }
    public double area(){
       return (double) (height * width);
}
```

and this main method

```
public class TestRect{

    public static void main(String[] args){
        double x = Double.parseDouble(args[0]);
        double y = Double.parseDouble(args[1]);
        double height = Double.parseDouble(args[2]);
        double width = Double.parseDouble(args[3]);
        Rect rect = new Rect (x, y, height, width);
        double area = Rect.area();     

    }    
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You would need to call the method on an instance of the class.

This code:

```
Rect rect = new Rect (x, y, height, width);
double area = Rect.area();
```

Should be:

```
Rect rect = new Rect (x, y, height, width);
double area = rect.area();
              ^ check here
                you use rect variable, not Rect class
                Java is Case Sensitive
```

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 options.

1. Make the method static.
2. Create an instance of the class which implements the method and call the method using the instance.

Which one to chose is purely a *design decision*.